# BizTalk 2009 custom adapter 64 bit

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk2006r2

Does anyone know what the registry settings should look like in order to get a 64 bit custom adapter to show up in the BizTalk admin console? I have created a 32 bit adapter, but would like to port it to 64 bit, but there's no information on creating custom 64 bit adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer but I was running out of room in the comment section.

The BizTalk Scheduled Task adapter 3.0 supports 64 bit.  You might be able to figure it out by looking at the [project](http://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/49542#).

The 3.0 version seems to use the same .reg file.  I wonder if the keys are the same but the 64 but version of [regedit](https://serverfault.com/questions/7973/is-there-a-distinction-between-64-bit-and-32-bit-regedit) is used.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{A35C0D84-DAE6-4de0-BDCC-3A20426AF41D}]
@="Biztalk ScheduledTask Adapter"
"AppID"="{12A6EBAA-CF68-4B58-B36E-A5A19B22C04E}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{A35C0D84-DAE6-4de0-BDCC-3A20426AF41D}\BizTalk]
@="BizTalk"
"TransportType"="Schedule"
"Constraints"=dword:00001019

"ReceiveLocation_PageProv"="{2DE93EE6-CB01-4007-93E9-C3D71689A280}"

"InboundEngineCLSID"="{91D61783-DE7E-47ea-BC44-95AF3B825F9D}"
"InboundTypeName"="ScheduledTaskAdapter.ScheduledReceiver"
"InboundAssemblyPath"="C:\\Program Files\\Biztalk ScheduledTask Adapter\\ScheduledTaskAdapter.dll"


"AdapterMgmtTypeName"="ScheduledTaskAdapterManagement.AdapterManagement"
"AdapterMgmtAssemblyPath"="C:\\Program Files\\Biztalk ScheduledTask Adapter\\ScheduledTaskAdapterManagement.dll"
"PropertyNameSpace"="http://schemas.custom.com/Biztalk/2003/scheduledtask-properties"
"AliasesXML"="<AdapterAliasList><AdapterAlias>schedule://</AdapterAlias></AdapterAliasList>"
"ReceiveLocationPropertiesXML"="<CustomProps><AdapterConfig vt=\"8\"/></CustomProps>"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{A35C0D84-DAE6-4de0-BDCC-3A20426AF41D}\Implemented Categories]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{A35C0D84-DAE6-4de0-BDCC-3A20426AF41D}\Implemented Categories\{7F46FC3E-3C2C-405B-A47F-8D17942BA8F9}]
@=""
```